# Magento text field attribute's value collection

Tags: magento, custom-attributes

In Magento I setup a product attribute called "Vendor"(Text Field type). 
I would like to get the unique collection of all vendor's values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this.....................

```
 $Collection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() ->addAttributeToSelect('vendor')->groupByAttribute('vendor');
    foreach($Collection as $each)
    {
    echo "<br/>".$each['vendor'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$attribute_value = $product->getVendor();` //for vendor attribute(type text field)

**UNIQUE ATTRIBUTE**

```
// specify the attribute code
$attributeCode = 'vendor';

// build and filter the product collection
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('notnull' => true))
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('neq' => ''))
        ->addAttributeToSelect($attributeCode);

// get all distinct attribute values
$usedAttributeValues = array_unique($products->getColumnValues($attributeCode));
```